# How can I access properties from my subclasses?

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, subclass

I having problem to access the properties from my subclasses. I have defined the superclass and than I've created the subclasses that inherited from super class. I Initialized  my superclass inside my subclasses.

I have a class called Box. Inside this class I have a property called Offer that's of type OfferType.

var Offer: OfferType?

Than I've created the class OfferType and set some properties to inside it.

```
class OfferType {

    var Name: String?
    var Image: UIImage?
    var Description: String?

    init(Name: String, Image: UIImage, Description: String) {
        self.Name = Name
        self.Image = Image
        self.Description = Description   
    }
}
```

Than I created 3 subclass of OfferType

```
class Discount: OfferType {

    var Quantity: Int?

    init() {
        super.init(Name: "Discount", Image: UIImage(named: "Discount")!, Description: "nice")
    }   
}

class FreeShipping: OfferType  {

    var From: String?
    var To: String?

    init() {
        super.init(Name: "FreeShiping", Image: UIImage(named: "FreeShipping")!, Description: "lalaa")
    }   
}

class BoGoF: OfferType {

    lazy var SecondProduct = String()

    init() {
        super.init(Name: "BoGoF", Image: UIImage(named: "BoGoF")!, Description: "boh")
    }    
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the property of the subclass after Assign the subclass as property Offer inside BOX class.

I can't do it, the only options Xcode gives to me is to access the properties of superclass (OfferType )

I need to access the property Quantity of subclass Discount.

Here is Where I'm trying to access the properties

First I assign the subclass to the property in class Box

newBox.Offer = Discount

Now I'm trying to get the properties of Discount and It doesn't give to me

newBox.Offer. [image: Just Here]

I tried to cast it but It didn't work

[image]

My class newbox is defined like that

[image]

That's how the class Box is defined

[image: Class Box]

Comment: Edit this and show us what you what you are saying. I see the classes here, and that's a great start, but I don't see where you are trying to access any properties. I think I know what you are saying, and it's a quick fix, however, could you show us?

Comment: Edited just right now

Comment: Show us how newBox.offer is defined. Never mind, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `newBox` instance probably has the `offer` property defined as `OfferType`.

Even though you put an instance of `Discount` inside the `offer` property, the compiler has no way to know that since all you've told the compiler is that `offer` will contain an `OfferType`. It has no way to know the **specific** `OfferType` that will be contained there.

You have to cast `offer` to the type you expect. I suggest you look into `as` and `is`. Here is an example:

```
if let discount = newBox.offer as? Discount {
   print("Discount Quantity is \(discount.quantity)")
}
```

Here the `as?` keyword basically tells the compiler the following:

> is `newBox.offer` a kind of `Discount`? If so return that, otherwise,
>   return nil.

Comment: I tried to do that before, it's giving me error type dude.

Comment: Please show how `offer` is defined  in `newBox`. Also detail the error you are obtaining.

Comment: You have to use `as?` not `as!`, otherwise an if...let isn't valid.

Comment: Perfect buddy it did work. I would like to understand a thing. Doing like that I'm assigning the property Quantity to my instance newBox ? or the Constant discount ? I mean , if I need to access it in next steps the property will be set ?

Comment: You've set an instance of `Discount` on the `Offer` property. Since a `Discount` is a kind of `OfferType`, this is allowed. Without casting (using `as?` or `as!`), the system only knows that an `OfferType` is inside `Offer`, it cannot access the specifics of the `OfferType`. I think your design pattern may have a flaw. This can be solved through `enums` much more elegantly, in my opinion. Read this: https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/

Comment: I didn't fully address your question. Your `quantity` is inside the `newBox.Offer` instance, a specialization of `OfferType` called `Discount` which contains a `quantity` property. The `quantity` you set will always be there, as long as `newBox` is alive in memory and you have not set the `Offer` to be another instance of `OfferType`

Comment: That's perfect man , you are really precise. Thanks for the Help! Good things to you ! I got it now, I'm gonna read the article as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, my pleasure. Good luck in your coding endeavours.

Comment: ... and do read that article because I think enums have much potential for what you're trying to do here! Good luck.